# Split ID's Up In Tables In While Loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following database table:

```
AWARD_ID   |  NOMINEE_ID   |  VOTER_ID  |  MULTI_CODE
------------------------------------------------------
5          | 3             |  1         |  9326
5          | 4             |  1         |  9326
5          | 5             |  3         |  8746
```

I need to display these results in tables grouped by MULTI_CODE, so for example:

So it would look like

```
<h1>Multi Code: 9326</h1>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Nominee: 3</td><td>Nominee: 4</td>
</tr>
</table>

<h1>Multi Code: 8746</h1>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Nominee: 5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is my SQL + PHP so far:

```
$nomineedetails = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT AWARD_ID, NOMINEE_ID, VOTER_ID, MULTI_CODE 
FROM b_awards_votes WHERE AWARD_ID = '5'");
$multi_code = -1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($nomineedetails))
{
$awardID = $row['AWARD_ID'];
$nomineeID = $row['NOMINEE_ID'];
$voterID = $row['VOTER_ID'];
$multiCode = $row['MULTI_CODE'];

print "<h2>$multiCode</h2>";

if ($multi_code != $multiCode) {

print "<table><tr>";

$multi_code = $multiCode;
}

print "<td>Nominee: $nomineeID</td>";";

}
</tr></table>
```

With this I get this:

```
 8746

 9326

 Nominee: 3

 9326

 Nominee: 4 Nominee: 5
```

Why am I getting the 9326 above the Nominee 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I suggest to order your results by MULTI_CODE to have the correct sorting when looping through the results.

Then, in your loop you always print the headline with the multi code, regardless being different to the previous one.

Please have a look at this code. It isn't tested, so please be aware that there might be errors in it:

```
$nomineedetails = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT AWARD_ID, NOMINEE_ID, VOTER_ID, MULTI_CODE 
FROM b_awards_votes WHERE AWARD_ID = '5' ORDER BY MULTI_CODE ASC");
$multi_code = -1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($nomineedetails))
{
    $awardID = $row['AWARD_ID'];
    $nomineeID = $row['NOMINEE_ID'];
    $voterID = $row['VOTER_ID'];
    $multiCode = $row['MULTI_CODE'];

    if ($multi_code != $multiCode) {
        if($multi_code !== -1) {
            print "</table>";
        }
        print "<h2>$multiCode</h2>";
        print "<table>";

        $multi_code = $multiCode;
    }

    print "<tr><td>Nominee: $nomineeID</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Works a treat! Just need to remove the double "; at the end :-) Thank you very much for your help!